# Sails.js provide and yield blocks

Tags: node.js, sails.js

In Ruby on Rails, there is a block called **<% provide:titleName %>** and **<% yield:titleName %>** that can be used to switch out text when rendering from page to page. 
Is there an equivalent method in Sails.js that mimics this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is if you use the standard ejs templating

IN the HTML file use:

```
<%= variablename %> //This will be replaced by the data in variablename
```

In the Controller method used to serve the view use:

```
res.view("viewname", {variablename: someValue});
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, let me know!

Comment: Hey Adam, I was wondering, wouldnt I be able to add more variableName: someValue into the res.view? For example: **res.view("viewname", {variableName1: someValue1, variableName2: someValue2});** Sorry I am very new to sails and eagerly trying to learn with the limited amount of examples online

Comment: Absolutely, you can also pass in an array and use loops in your ejs templating to access variables in the array. I have views that pass in about a dozen or more different values into a single view.  The way you have it looks correct to me.